# Import PFX file in Client machine

Tags: c#, certificate

We need to register my company certificate on several client machines.

I have used the following code to register using C#:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("D:\temp.pfx","password");
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher,
                                        StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Add(certificate);
store.Close();
```

It works correctly, but I don't want to ship the pfx file on the client machines.

Should I access the file from the web or call a web service to access the pfx file?

Can any one please help me on this ?

Answer (score 2):

> Shall i access the file from the web/ call web service to access the pfx file.

As long as you're publishing your *public* key, you can do it in whatever way you like.